# Windows Forms App - Trying to run an ps1 script always getting back with "null"

Tags: c#, powershell

Im trying to make an C# toolbox. I got my design part done and now Im trying to implement my pre-done ps1 scripts, but i cant seem to find a way for me to run the script after clicking button.
Would appreciate any help. Im running the forms on .Net 6.0 in VS22, with the latest PowerShellGet package.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using static System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats;
using Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using HexTB2.Properties;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

namespace XXXX
{
    public partial class GameClientsMenu : Form
    {

        private PowerShell powerShellInstance;

        public GameClientsMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponents

            powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
        }

        private void SCIB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Path to your PowerShell script
            string scriptPath = @"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Project\XXXX\Resources\steaminstall.ps1";

            try
            {
                // Add the script to the PowerShell instance
                powerShellInstance.AddScript(scriptPath);

                // Invoke the script
                powerShellInstance.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error executing PowerShell script: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried multiple ways of executing the powershell script in C#, i got it working once, but it stopped working when i restarted the app throwing error -
`no overload for SCIB_Click matches delegate EventHandler`
or comming back with null.

every way i tried to execute the ps1 script failed.

In GameClientsMenu.Designer.cs

```
SCIB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
private System.Windows.Forms.Button SCIB;
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I wasn`t really sure what was needed for people to be able to help me, so I decided to post the whole form.cs - updated the post with only the problem parts and needed info (or so i think atleast).

Comment: Can you add the code creating the `Button` instance?

Comment: in designer.cs -  
SCIB = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
private System.Windows.Forms.Button SCIB;

not sure if this is the thing you were asking for.

Comment: Add the code means add to your question not to a comment

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution after searching a lot more.**

This is the solution that works as i want it to.

```
        private void SCIB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string scriptPath = @"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Project\XXXX\Resources\steaminstall.ps1";

            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "powershell.exe";
                psi.Arguments = $"-File \"{scriptPath}\"";
                Process.Start(psi);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error opening PowerShell window: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, but this is a suboptimal workaround (creation of a PowerShell child process), not a solution based on fixing your own approach (using the PowerShell SDK to make an in-process call), and also doesn't explain the error message you got.